# Is there an option to ad a black border to a image nested in a ggdraw?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

```
library(cowplot)
ggdraw() +
    draw_plot(p) +
  draw_image(magick::image_read("img.png"),
             scale = .25, x = .4, y = .1)
```

Here `p` is not even important, I would just like to add a black border to `img.png`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(cowplot)
library(magick)

tiger <- image_read_svg('http://jeroen.github.io/images/tiger.svg', width = 350)

ggdraw() +
  draw_image(
    tiger,
    scale = .5, x = -0.25, y = 0.25
  ) +
  draw_image(
    tiger |> magick::image_border(color = 'black'),
    scale = .5, x = 0.25, y = 0.25
  ) +
  draw_image(
    tiger |> magick::image_border(color = 'firebrick'),
    scale = .5, x = -0.25, y = -0.25
  ) +
  draw_image(
    tiger |> magick::image_border(color = 'navy'),
    scale = .5, x = 0.25, y = -0.25
  )
```

[image]